# tinymce load image list already available on the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, list, tinymce

I have this jquery code:

```
  $.each( imgPath, function( key, value ) {
  $('#imgul').append('<div draggable=\"true\" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" id="image[]"  class="checkboxImg" value="' + value + '">
  <img src="' + value + '" class="imgList" ></div>');   
  $("#imgRes").replaceWith($("#imgRes").clone());
  });
```

which loads series of images in

```
 <ul id=\"imgul\" style=\"margin-left:10px; width:500px;\">                                 
 </ul>
```

In this way i have already the list of images under TinyMCE 4.1.9 editor frame.
By clicking on "Images" > "list", I have to send them inside the editor image list.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE provides a possibility to add custom button, which allows me to trig any javascript event.

It's really sufficient to insert this code inside the page and write some custom jQuery or else code to get elements by id:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...

   theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'example,..'

   setup : function(ed) {
      // Register example button
      ed.addButton('example', {
         title : 'example.desc',
         image : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
         onclick : function() {
            ed.windowManager.alert('Hello world!! Selection: ' + ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));
         }
      });
   }
});
```